# Парсинг видео с вебкамер

Tags: android

подскажите пожалуйста , что нужно изучить чтобы написать приложение для просмотра онлайн вебкамер (из интернета) на телефоне. Что можно почитать или посмотреть.

Answer (score 3):

Если камеры транслируют видео поток в формате соответствующем [спецификациям Android API](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) тогда можно просто взять обычный [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), и просто открывать в нем поток.

Вот [пример](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-video-streaming-videoview-tutorial/) простейшего плеера основанный на VideoView - обертка того же MediaPlayer'a.
А вот [пример](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-3/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java.shtml) плеера с использованием MediaPlayer + SurfaceView. Лично я предпочитаю 2й вариант.

В случае, если формат потока андроид не поддерживает, можно либо транскодировать стрим камеры в формат который андроид подерживает на сервере и читать его вышеописанным способом.

Еще можно взять существующие плееры типа MX или VLC и использовать их. В случае VLC, если он читает ваш поток, то можно взять его код (он открытый), скомпилировать и менять в нем то, что вам нужно.

Comment: в общем правильно, но есть достаточно много извращенных веб-камер, в которых так просто все не получится.    
Что я хочу этим сказать? - Нужно подстраиваться под каждую веб-камеру отдельно.

Comment: @metalurgus, cогласен. У меня просто уже был опыт чего-то подобного. Только у меня все обошлось конвертированием UDP потока в HTTP без изменений формата видео при помощи программки UDP proxy. В принципе транскодировать большинство типов аудио/видео потоков в http stream можно при помощи FFMPEG. Другой вопрос на сколько можно нагружать этим сервер.